# PHP - Display table of external website

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I need to display a table from an external website on my own website. The reason is that the content of this table changes daily and I don't want to change it manually on my website.

This is my approach so far:

```html
<!-- This is the exemplary HTML code of the external website -->
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <!-- some content -->
    <div id="table-id">
      <table>
        <!-- table content -->
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- some other content -->
  </body>
</html>


<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.my-source-website.com');
$homepage = htmlentities($homepage);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHTML($homepage);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $selector->query('//div[@id="table-id"]');

foreach($result as $node) {
  echo $node->textContent;
}
?>
```

This code seems to be not correct. I'm getting a kind of empty result. Am I on the right way to solve my issue?

I know I could solved this issue with an regular expression, but I've read that this wouldn't be a flexible good solution.

Comment: What is the `htmlentities()` doing in there? You certainly do _not_ want to modify the page source before processing it...

Comment: Apart from that you should take a look into your http servers error log file. Since you do not implement any error checking/handing whatsoever you should at least monitor that file.

Comment: Without htmlentities() I'm getting errors.

Comment: And... _what_ errors are those?

Comment: And please add the exact URL of the page you want to rip. That should not be an issue, since it is published anyway, _except_ you break their terms of use, obviously...

Comment: It's a warning: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity  
Source URL: http://bttv.click-tt.de/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTTDE.woa/wa/teamPortrait?teamtable=2357992&pageState=rueckrunde&championship=B100+2016%2F17&group=279068

I need the table with the ID: content-row2

Comment: That sounds like invalid html markup you receive. You won't get rid of that issue by `htmlentities()`, that will only alter the content such that it is not html any more to the dom parser.

Comment: Well, it's the markup of the source I need. Do you have any solution how to get the html data I need?

Comment: Not if I cannot try myself. Since you do not provide the page URL there is little I can do.

Comment: I did provide a URL in my previous comment.

Comment: I do apologize - I did not at all see that URL before. Strange.

Comment: Well, the html markup I load from that URL does not contain any table definition with an `id`. So how do you want to select by an `id`?

Comment: I need the whole HTML inside the DIV tag with id="content-row2"

Comment: Ok. Actually I have no issues at all using your code with the correct identifier. I do not get any warning, instead I get the contents of that node.